# What will be the latency if I add AWS WAF on top of CloudFront CDN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, latency, amazon-waf

I have added a WAF on top of CDN, will there be any latency issues for this? if there how much latency will be there?
And what is the latency for AWF WAF?

I have added WAF on top of CDN, i just want to know if there is any latency issues for the CDN requests which goes directly to CDN and the requests which goes through WAF

Answer (score 0):

When you use AWS WAF on Amazon CloudFront, your rules run in all AWS Edge Locations, located around the world close to your end users. Shouldn't cause any significant impact.
[See FAQs here](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/faqs/#:%7E:text=This%20means%20security%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20come%20at%20the%20expense%20of%20performance)